# Nested FormView with UserControls, events not firing correctly

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls, nested, formview

I'm in the process of reworking a pretty complicated form.  This form has multiple sub forms.  The original incarnation was to create all of these panels that were hidden and such (no my design, what I'm trying to fix).

What I'm ending up with is a FormView where the Edit mode consists of a typical form and there is one sub form with it.  Now the subform shows a GridView when in ReadOnly mode, which is tied to a callback edit method that will change the index of the subform to the proper one and change it to Edit mode.  All of the data for these are through SqlDataObjects.

To simplify the process, I have put the subform into a usercontrol and I include the user control in both the Edit and ReadOnly portions of the main form.  So when the main form is ReadOnly, it shows the usercontrol in it's default mode which is ReadOnly thus showing the grid.  This part works nicely.

When the user opens the main form in Edit mode, the subform is display in grid mode as expected (and the column in the grid that houses the Edit button is rendered visible).  This works fine as well.

When I click on the edit button and change the form to Edit mode, everything works as expected.  I can see that the flow through the mainform to the subform (via debugging) is going as expected.

Now when I click the update button, which is just a simple LinkButton that has the CommandName set (just like ever other form view that works) I notice that the callback goes to the subform (skipping the databinding of the mainform -- which is also expect) but the update call is never rendered to the SqlDataObject.

I have a OnUpdating/OnInserting/OnSelecting for each of my SqlDataObjects just for debuging purposes, and it's never hit.  The usercontrol goes straight to ReadOnly mode after the postback.  I don't think it's a DataBinding issue.

Anyone seen this with nested form controls?  Specifically, usercontrols housing FormView nested in a FormView?

I don't might dropping the entire UserControl and just putting the subform directly inside the mainform, but I'd rather know the proper solution that to just play around until it works...

Comment: It appears that the bigger underlying problem with the scenario is that the subform is losing it's formviewmode state on postback, whereas the mainform is not.  Thanks for the -1 comment.  There seems to be several similar questions on this on various blogs but in typical fashion it appears that once they figure it out they don't share the knowledge :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that handling callbacks from nested formviews requires it to be treated like it's a dynamic control, even though it's part of the template.  When the child form is force to Edit mode (by setting it to the default) it processes the postback as expected.  When it's left to the default settings it fails to process the postback as expected.

I would like to have presented some sample code, and I will probably do so at a later time (which is why I'm assuming I got the -1 within a minute of posting) but there seems to be no functional samples anywhere regarding nested forms (samples that work anyway).

The short fix was to put the second form outside the scope of the first (but still within the same user control) and then do a couple callbacks for change detection.

With that said, if you have a form within a form, and their b